# Docker: transaction check error

Tags: docker, centos7

I am trying to install docker and following https://get.docker.com/

I am on CentOS7

```
-bash-4.2$ cd
-bash-4.2$ wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
+ sudo -E sh -c 'sleep 3; yum -y -q install docker-engine'
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib/systemd/system/blk-availability.service from install of device-mapper-7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package lvm2-7:2.02.105-14.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/blkdeactivate from install of device-mapper-7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package lvm2-7:2.02.105-14.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man8/blkdeactivate.8.gz from install of device-mapper-7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package lvm2-7:2.02.105-14.el7.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

Anyone know what this error means and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated with:

```
sudo yum update
```

Now docker command works now

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `device-mapper-7` is incompatible with `lvm2-7` on your system.

You could try deinstalling `device-mapper-7`. Then try to run the Docker installation one more time.